# Execute STUFF return query string without storing into variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm preparing `select` query using `STUFF` function.

Given:

```
DECLARE @GeoID VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Table1'

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM ['+@TableName+'] t WHERE ( Select GeoPath from dbo.TableGeo Where GeoID = '''+f.Item+''').STIntersects(geometry::Point(ISNULL(Lat,''''), ISNULL(Long,''''),4326))=1' 
             FROM f_Split(@GeoID,',') f
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,11,'')
```

Here I want to execute the `select union all` query without storing it into variable and then execute.

Comment: *"Here I want to execute the select union all query without storing it into variable and then execute."* You can't; when you create a dynamic statement you must first put it into a variable as you *cannot* pass an expression to `sp_executesql` for the parameters (including `@stmt`). Also, you really need to fix that injection issue you have. `'...['+@TableName+']...'` is **not** safe. What do you think would happen if the value of `@TableName` was :`'sys].[tables]; DROP TABLE Table1; --'`? [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: You aren't executing a STUFF query, you're using the XML technique to concatenate a string you just split. What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve and what are you trying to produce from that concatenation?

Comment: For example, there's only *one* table in this query, so why use UNION ALL? If you want to search for specific GeoIDs, why not use an `IN` clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Do you really think `IN` clause does it with `.STIntersects`?

Comment: @MAK I think this code is so convoluted it's no longer visible what it's supposed to do. Why would `IN` have anything to do with `STIntersects`? It's comparing `GeoID` with the values in `'1,2,3,4'`. Essentially it's an expensive `GeoID in (1,2,3,4)` that suffers from SQL Injection issues. As for `STIntersects`, it's tryong to work with a single point that may contain empty values. When that doesn't throw, it will be extremely slow.

Comment: @MAK you can selecting all geopaths whose ID is in that string is as easy as `Select GeoPath from dbo.TableGeo Where GeoID in (' + @geoID  + '...)`. Of course, this is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. That query can easily be used with either a JOIN or CROSS APPLY to find matching points in whatever table you target, BUT that may not be able to use any spatial indexes. What does GeoPath contain? There are ways to speed up spatial queries that depend on the shapes. Eg if it's a polygon,a bounding rectangle can turn a spatial query into a simple range search

Comment: If you *do* need to pass multiple values, you would be better off with a table-type parameter/variable. Then you can `JOIN` to the parameter/variable and not have injection open code; it's 2019 and there is by far enough resources explaining why injection is ***bad*** and should never occur.

Comment: @MAK you could write `select t.* from ThatTable t inner join TableGeo g g on t.ThatPoint.Intersects(g.GeoPath) where GeoID IN (1,2,3,4)`. The point should be an actual `geography` column covered by an index to get any performance benefit. The chances of a *point* intersecting an open path though, are essentially 0, unless it matches one of the path's nodes **exactly**. If the path *doesn't* contain an open path, `STContains` would be better.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Your last comment done the job! I just added `STIntersects` in place of `Intersects` and in place of `t.ThatPoint.` to `(geometry::Point(ISNULL(t.Lat,''), ISNULL(t.Long,''),4326))` which works fine.

Comment: @MAK you still haven't explained what you're trying to do. GIS and spatial queries is nothing new, in fact SQL Server was a late-comer even back in 2008. Some GIS queries are *several* orders of magnitude faster than others. Some slow ones can be accelerated 10x times by using techniques like bounding boxes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have stored `Geometry Path`(calculated of Lat and Long) which maybe of any shape (Rectangle, Triangle etc) in the table `TableGeo`. And in the table `Table1` I have only `Lat` and `Long` not fully calculated `Geometry path`. I just need to get those records which matching with each other or just found in with `Geometry Path` by giving `GeoID` as input.

Answer (score 0):

The code works when you switch your custom split function for the one built in to recent versions of SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @GeoID VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Table1'

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM ['+@TableName+'] t WHERE ( Select GeoPath from dbo.TableGeo Where GeoID = '''+f.value+''').STIntersects(geometry::Point(ISNULL(Lat,''''), ISNULL(Long,''''),4326))=1' 
             FROM string_split(@GeoID,',') f
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,11,'')
```

Comment: At least fix the huge injection issue.

Comment: Also, the OP explicitly tagged `sql-server-2012`. `STRING_SPLIT` doesn't exist on 2012.